# generic function to get entity list from entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to create a generic function to which I pass entity name and it returns the list of that entity type like this:

```
private List<Entity> GetEntityList(Entity entity)
{
    return context.entity.ToList();
}
```

where context is objectcontext.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: Do you have the table names pluralized (e.g. type 'Customer', but table name 'Customers') or not?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
public static class ObjectContextExtensions
    {
        public static ObjectQuery<TEntity> GetEntities<TEntity>(this ObjectContext context) where TEntity : class {
            var query = from pd in context.GetType().GetProperties()
                        where pd.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ObjectQuery<TEntity>))
                        select (ObjectQuery<TEntity>)pd.GetValue(context, null);
            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
using (var objectContext = new ObjectContext())
            {
                var entities = objectContext.GetEntities<Entity>().ToList();
            }
```